# Joomla 4 webservices are not working

Tags: restful-api

I am trying the web services in Joomla 4. I have enabled SEF URLS, URL Rewriting on site configuration and I have set nginx according to https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_%28SEF%29_URLs_on_Nginx

I have download the postman urls from https://github.com/alexandreelise/j4x-api-collection

but they are not working.

They return 404.

Is there something else I should do?

Comment: Did you rename the htaccess.txt file? Is necessary for the API to work. Also, what end-point you trying?